# Cosine similarity returning wrong distance

Tags: java, text-mining, cosine-similarity

I have two vectors represented as a HashMap and I want to measure the similarity between them. I use the cosine similarity metric as in the following code:

```
public static void cosineSimilarity(HashMap<Integer,Double> vector1, HashMap<Integer,Double> vector2){
double scalar=0.0d, v1Norm=0.0d, v2Norm=0.0d;

for(int featureId: vector1.keySet()){
   scalar+= (vector1.get(featureId)* vector2.get(featureId));
   v1Norm+= (vector1.get(featureId) * vector1.get(featureId));
   v2Norm+= (vector2.get(featureId) * vector2.get(featureId));
}

 v1Norm=Math.sqrt(v1Norm);
 v2Norm=Math.sqrt(v2Norm);

 double cosine= scalar / (v1Norm*v2Norm);
 System.out.println("v1 is: "+v1Norm+" , v2 is: "+v2Norm+" Cosine is: "+cosine);    
}
```

Strangely, two vectors that are supposed to be dissimilar come close to .9999 result which is just wrong!

Please note that the keys are exactly the same for both maps.

data file is here: [file](http://ge.tt/3TJFuqa/v/0?c)

File format:

FeatureId vector1_value vector2_value

Comment: Could we see the data for the two vectors?

Comment: Nothing about your code jumps out. I agree with Anders that we need to see the data.

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup sure. It is quite long vector though

Comment: @DotNet If it is really long, then you may be running into some issue with floating-point precision.  Even more reason why it would help to see the actual data.

Comment: @MatthewT.Staebler and all, thanks. I uploaded the data file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is fine.

The vectors are dominated by several large features. In those features, the two vectors are almost collinear, which is why the similarity measure is close to `1`.

I include the six largest features below. Look at the ratio of `vec2` over `vec1`: it's almost identical across those features.

```
feature     vec1    vec2        vec2/vec1

64806110    2875    1.85E+07    6.43E+03
64806108    5750    3.68E+07    6.40E+03
64806107    8625    5.49E+07    6.37E+03
64806106    11500   7.29E+07    6.34E+03
64806111    14375   9.07E+07    6.31E+03
64806109    17250   1.08E+08    6.28E+03
```